# Параллельное исполнение Python-функции через Boost.Python

Tags: c++, python, многопоточность, boost, boost.python

Секция данных:

```
static Market market;

// boost::asio::thread_pool thread_pool;

static std::unordered_map < std::string, std::unordered_map < std::string,
    std::pair < Market::path_t, std::string > > > data; // future
```

Настройка Python:

```
static Python_Initializer python_initializer;

static boost::python::object global = boost::python::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");

boost::python::exec("from analysis.src.main import run", global, global);

static boost::python::object module = global["run"];
```

В `Python_Initializer` вызывается `Py_Initialize`. `static` здесь и в секции данных нужен для избежания повторного конструирования объектов, т.к. данный код размещается в функции DLL библиотеки, вызываемой в цикле извне. Функция `run` является потокобезопасной.

Основное исполнение:

```
for (const auto & asset : market.assets())
{
    for (const auto & scale : market.scales())
    {
        auto file = market.get(asset, scale, 250);

        //std::packaged_task < std::string() > task([asset, scale, file, &module]()
        //{
        //    return boost::python::extract < std::string > (
        //      module(asset.c_str(), scale.c_str(), file.string().c_str()));
        //});

        //data[asset][scale] = std::make_pair(std::move(file),
        //  boost::asio::post(thread_pool, std::move(task)));

        std::string message = boost::python::extract < std::string >(
            module(asset.c_str(), scale.c_str(), file.string().c_str()));

        data[asset][scale] = std::make_pair(std::move(file), std::move(message));
    }
}
```

В текущем последовательном исполнении все работает. Однако, если добавить `thread_pool`, обернуть последний `std::string` в `data` с помощью `std::future` и заменить код в основном исполнении на тот, который сейчас закомментирован, то возникнет ошибка. Содержание ее ни о чем конкретном не говорит, ошибка на уровне Boost.Python, если отследить, то проблема с чтением/записью указателей при настройке какой-то callback функции.

**Вопрос**: как настроить Boost.Python, чтобы через него механизмами параллельного исполнения Boost и стандартной библиотеки можно было параллельно исполнять некоторую потокобезопасную Python функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общая идея -- использовать второй поток для интерпретатора питон.

```
#include <Python.h>

#include <boost/python/exec.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>
#include <boost/python/import.hpp>
#include <boost/python/object.hpp>

void python (std::string fork, int m, int n) {
  const char *prog = "def ack(m, n):\n"
                     "  if m == 0:\n"
                     "    return n + 1\n"
                     "  elif n == 0:\n"
                     "    return ack(m - 1, 1)\n"
                     "  else:\n"
                     "    return ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))";

  Py_Initialize();
  try {
    std::cout << fork << std::endl;

    boost::python::object mainModule = boost::python::import("__main__");
    boost::python::object mainNamespace = mainModule.attr("__dict__");

    std::stringstream commandstream;
    commandstream << "ack(" << m << "," << n << ")";
    std::string command = commandstream.str();
    boost::python::exec(prog, mainNamespace, mainNamespace);
    int val = boost::python::extract<int>(boost::python::eval(command.c_str(), mainNamespace, mainNamespace));
    std::cout << fork << " result: " << val << std::endl;
  } catch (boost::python::error_already_set const &e) {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    python("f1", 3, 4);
  } else if (pid > 0) {
    python("f2", 3, 3);

    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
  } else {
    std::cout << "Fork failed." << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Ссылки по теме::

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/18213159
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/45489225
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/41240610
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/28968123

Comment: Только не *поток*, а *процесс*. Функция [fork()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) создает новый процесс (*`process`*) с отдельным адресным пространством, а не поток (*`thread`*), исполняющийся в том же пространстве, что и thread  (функция [pthread_create](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create)) создавший его